# Python compare type of (str, enum) classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have multiple enums defined with

```py
from enum import Enum

class EnumA(str, Enum):
    RED = "red"

class EnumB(str, Enum):
    BLUE = "blue"
```

How do I compare the type of these classes/enums with say `x=EnumA.RED`? The following doesn't work.

```
type(x) is enum
type(x) is EnumType
type(x) is Enum
```

I don't want to compare the classes directly, since I have a lot of enums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` has type `EnumA`, none of the other things.

1. `enum` is a module.
2. `EnumType` <strike>isn't defined at all</strike> is the metaclass used to define `Enum`.
3. `Enum` is a class defined in the `enum` module; it's the *parent* class of `EnumA`.

In any case, never compare `type` objects directly. Use `isinstance` to determine if a value is of a given type. (For checking the type of an object, you virtually never care about the difference between a class and its superclass(es).)

```
>>> isinstance(x, EnumA)
True
>>> isinstance(x, Enum)
True
```

The latter is true because `EnumA` is a subclass of `Enum`.

Comment: Well, there is actually [`EnumType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.EnumType). It is the `type(Enum)` (metaclass).

Comment: Bah, I thought I remembered it being named `EnumMeta`.

Comment: @chepner: It was.  It kept confusing me in the tracebacks so I renamed it.  (`EnumMeta` is still a working alias.)

Comment: Why isn't that mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: It is in the [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#enum).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
isinstance(x, Enum)
```

Answer (score 1):

To know the type of the variable you should compare it with EnumA or EnumB, example :

type(x) is EnumA